# Tabs interfering with application- and activity themes

Tags: android, tabs, themes

We're developing an android application that has several different tabs. We've been trying to apply a theme to entire application, and we've also tried applying a theme to specific activities. Neither has any effect.

I have this style-file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="recapmain">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/recapButton</item>
        <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/recapText</item>
    </style>
    <style name="recapButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
        <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
    </style>
    <style name="recapText">
        <item name="android:textSize">30dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The application tag in the manifest file looks like this:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/recapmain">

    <activity android:name="appname"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

This doesn't work. The application simply does not react to the theme. If I set a specific view to use one of the styles, it's works perfectly. So, I can do this in the xml file for an activity:

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/OverviewButtonYears" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:text="@string/years"
android:onClick="years"
style="@style/recapButton"
/>
```

That will style the button appropriately.

we've also tried applying the theme to a specific activity tag, with no result.

Now, what *does* work, is removing the intent-filter-tag from the application tag, and putting it in an activity tag, like this:

```
<activity android:name=".PolicyTab"  >
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

That starts the specific activity only, and it does have the appropriate theme.

My question then, is, why? We've gussed that it has something to do with the tabs, since starting only one activity enables the theme. What do we have to do to get it to work *with* tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wany your main application theme to be `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` with customized control styles, then you should extend that theme with your preferences:

```
<style name="recapmain" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
```

This line will adopt the styles of the parent theme into `recapmain`, and inside you can write your own preferences (as you already have for `buttonStyle` and `textViewStyle`).

Inside your `androidManifest.xml` you set the application theme to your custom style:

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@style/recapmain">
```

**Update**
Your styles.xml should contain:

```
<style name="recapmain" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/recapButton</item>
    <item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/recapText</item>
</style>
<style name="recapButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
    <item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>
</style>
<style name="recapText" parent="android:style/Widget.TextView">
    <item name="android:textSize">30dip</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>
```

Comment: We've encountered another problem now, though. While the application recognises the theme "recapmain", it doesn't seem to apply to references @style/recapButton and @style/recapText at all. It does recognise the parent "NoTitleBar" and if I write something like this: 

<style name="recapmain" parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
/../
<item name="android:background">#FF0000</item>

it will apply the background color to everything. But if I remove that tag, it will not apply anything to any buttons or textviews. 

Any other ideas?

Comment: you should leave the buttonStyle and textViewStyle items in your `recapmain` style tag. Only those inside that tag (or other referenced style tags) will be applied. So your style xml should remain the same as in your post, just put the `parent="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` declaration in your `recapmain`.

Comment: Yes, but the problem seems to be that those references aren't working. It's as if @style/recapButton doesn't point to the <style> whose name is "recapButton", because the buttons aren't styled at all. So the application recognises the "recapmain" style, but the references inside it don't work.

Comment: Then make sure, that you didn't apply any other styles to lower levels of your application (specific layouts/views/activities). I've tried your code with setting nothing but the application theme, and all my buttons got red, my textviews got huge letters.

Comment: I haven't applied any styles anywhere else in the code. It's the references that don't work. If set "textColor" to #FFFFFF directly under the "recapmain"-style tag, the text will turn white. If I instead have #FFFFFF in another style tag ("recapText") and refer the textColor to @style/recapText, it doesn't work.